# In reference to Ashenmoor Liege

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What abilities target [Ashenmoor Liege](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAshenmoor%20Liege%5d) that triggers 'Whenever Ashenmoor Liege becomes the target of a spell or ability an opponent controls, that player loses 4 life.'  Would deathtouch qualify?

Answer (score 3):

Deathtouch does not qualify because it doesn't target. Note Ashenmoor Liege says "... becomes the *target* of a spell or ability an opponent controls". Spells and abilities that target will use the word 'target' (Auras also count as targeted spells). For example, the text of [Seal Away](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSeal%20Away%5d) says (emphasis mine):

> When Seal Away enters the battlefield, exile **target** tapped creature an opponent controls until Seal Away leaves the battlefield.

So casting Seal Away on Ashenmoor Liege triggers the ability. Deathtouch's text, however, says:

> Deathtouch (Any amount of damage this deals to a creature is enough to destroy it.)

Hence it doesn't target, and it doesn't trigger the ability.

Comment: "Spells and abilities that target will use the word 'target'" There is one big exception to that, and that's Aura spells. They target even though they do not say so.